# PHP SOAP doesn't catch SAP PI/XI SOAP fault

Tags: php, soap, sap-pi, sap-xi

I do SOAP request to SAP PI web service. This service returns SOAP fault like that:

> ```
> <SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
>    <SOAP:Body>
>       <SOAP:Fault>
>          <faultcode>SOAP:Server</faultcode>
>          <faultstring>Server Error</faultstring>
>          <detail>
>             <s:SystemError xmlns:s="http://sap.com/xi/WebService/xi2.0">
>                <context>XIAdapter</context>
>                <code>ADAPTER.JAVA_EXCEPTION</code>
>                <text>com.sap.aii.af.service.cpa.CPAObjectNotFoundException: Couldn't
>                        retrieve binding for the given channelId: Binding:CID=null;
>                at com.sap.aii.af.service.cpa.impl.lookup.AbstractLookupManager.getBindingByChannelId(AbstractLookupManager.java:173)
>                at com.sap.aii.adapter.soap.web.MessageServlet.doPost(MessageServlet.java:449)
>                ...
>                at com.sap.engine.core.thread.execution.CentralExecutor$SingleThread.run(CentralExecutor.java:327)</text>
>             </s:SystemError>
>          </detail>
>       </SOAP:Fault>
>    </SOAP:Body>
> </SOAP:Envelope>
> ```

In PHP, I do as follows:

```
$client = new SoapClient('path/to/wsdl', array(
            'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
            'exceptions' => true,
            'login' => 'some_login',
            'password' => 'some_password',
        ));
$result = $client->some_funtion("bla-bla-bla");
var_dump($result);
```

It prints *null*, but should throw an exception.

If I output the same XML (SOAP fault) in my own web service, I catch it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in *output* tag in WSDL. I have added this tag and it solve my problem

```
<wsdl:portType name="...">
     <wsdl:operation name="...">
         ...
         <wsdl:input message="..."/>
         <wsdl:output message="..."/> <!--- that tag-->
     </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you don't have a try/catch block.

Try this:

```
$client = new SoapClient('path/to/wsdl', array(
            'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
            'exceptions' => true,
            'login' => 'some_login',
            'password' => 'some_password',
        ));

try{
  $result = $client->some_funtion("bla-bla-bla");
} catch (SoapFault $e){
   exit('caught soap fault');
}
```

Comment: No, it is not cause of problem. Try/catch doens't help. Exception should throw php soap client, but it doesn't happen